# python send and receive data serially

Tags: python, serial-port, python-2.x, stm32

I'm trying communicate with STM32L152RB board through COM port 4  which accepts commands from COM4 and displays result in terminal using this code but it's not working ... I'm new to python please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

```
#Global Variables
ser = 0


def init_serial():
    COMNUM = 4          #Enter Your COM Port Number Here.
    global ser          #Must be declared in Each Function
    ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.baudrate = 9600
    ser.port = COMNUM - 1   #COM Port Name Start from 0

    #ser.port = '/dev/ttyUSB0' #If Using Linux

    #Specify the TimeOut in seconds, so that SerialPort
    #Doesn't hangs
    ser.timeout = 10
    ser.open()          #Opens SerialPort

    # print port open or closed
    if ser.isOpen():
        print 'dis' + ser.portstr




init_serial()

temp = raw_input('Type what you want to send, hit enter:\r\n')
ser.write('dis')         #Writes to the SerialPort

while 1:    
    bytes = ser.read()  #Read from Serial Port
    print 'You sent: ' + bytes      #Print What is Read from Port
```

Comment: What do you mean it isn't working?

Comment: i just took this code from somewhere else...  i need to continuous monitor com4 if i send for example display command then my stm32 board sends result through com4 and i need to display that that result...

Comment: i can communicate with the board by using Teraterm but i don't know how to interface with it by using python